# "Forest noises" - on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/forest-noise-mp3s

Is the above on topic? I'm tempted to say no, and would equate it to someone asking where to find a video of someone programming on SE, but thought it's worth throwing out there before I chuck my close vote in.